# flex-wrap with with 100% viewport width items do not come up at 100% on chrome mobile simulator

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, flexbox

- Open this inside chrome: https://s.codepen.io/matthewharwood/debug/JLqRYB/bYMdyGEqLWKr
- Observe how when on desktop it makes a 3x3 grid of items based on viewport width and height.
  [image: Desktop]
- Open up chrome inspector and go to any mobile device simulation view
  [image]
- Observe how items are no longer full width/height of the view port?

**Question:** Why do items on mobile not keep the 100% viewport for width?

CODE:

html:

1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6

CSS:

```
section {
  width: 300vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  > div {
    display: flex;

  }
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  &:nth-child(1) {
      background: purple;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
      background: red;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
      background: yellow;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
      background: green;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
      background: papayawhip;
  }
  &:nth-child(6) {
      background: orange;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

Viewport for mobile devices did work for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/aYrmwa

Comment: Because I want a 3 column grid of items.  300vw is 3 viewports or 3 columns.  Yours will make 1 column makes them all go down

Comment: sure got it! Just edited my answer. viewport was missing there. Now it's working.

Comment: Btw, change your "debug" view to "full" view mode on Codepen, otherwise will appear expired for others. cheers!

Comment: Whats the default content="width" size? it's weird that it's not the width of the device by default.

Comment: You can setup any width. As I understand b default it will fit the content not the screen size. That's why you need to define it as vw or 100% and to work properly on mobile devices needs to use the viewport to define the width device as 1:1 otherwise it won't respect the width size.